# Visual Studio Publish GIT repository (either local or remote) to Dev server without changed files that haven't been staged/committed

Tags: git, visual-studio, bitbucket

Perhaps this is something that already happens by default, but I'm working on a bunch of files that haven't been staged or committed, but another fix that was made more urgently needs to be published to our dev server.

I'm afraid that if I publish my local version of the development branch, it will publish the currently in-progress work on files that haven't been staged or committed.  Is there a way to publish the remote (Bitbucket Git) version of the development branch that only has committed changes, or does my local version of that branch if I publish it will only transfer the original version of uncommitted files?

Comment: When you said publish I supouse you refer to push. Push never transfer uncommitted files, so if that was your concern, don't worried about that.
Anyway when I think so you should have made a new hotfix  branch and publish that branch.
If I didn't understand what is the problem please do a more complete ask.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I just tried publishing and files that were not committed still overwrote items on the server.  I'm talking about a Visual Studio Publish.  Not a Push to a Git repository.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options
1) Stash your changes on the current branch or
2) Create a new branch for your existing changes, then switch back to the "develop" branch.

git stash temporarily shelves (or stashes) changes you've made to your working copy so you can work on something else, and then come back and re-apply them later on.

In Visual Studio Code (version 1.33.1) you can stash this way:
a) click on the Source Control icon (or Ctrl-Shift-G)
b) Click on the three dots at the top of the source control
c) Choose "Stash" in the menu
Then you can re-git from the origin and make changes to that.
Later, retrieve your stash.

Comment: Which version of VS are you speaking of?  If I show the Source control in the menu, it's grayed out, and hitting Ctrl-Shift-G does nothing...

Comment: I have Visual Studio Community - on both linux and windows. Could it be git is misconfigured in your IDE? (Look at File | Preferences | Settings & search for Git)

Comment: No Preferences or Settings under File.